# Script# Unit tests with DOM access

Tags: unit-testing, script#

I am trying to write unit test which suppose to access DOM, something simple like check if element exists.

I have created separte Test project, added QUnit for ASP.net MVC from Nuget and Script# Unit testing helpers. Added a reference to my Script# project.

I guess that I should run something like

```
    WebTest web = new WebTest();
    web.StartWebServer("/", 10258);
    Uri testUri = web.GetTestUri("/Test.html");
    WebTestResult ieResult = web.RunTest(testUri, WebBrowser.InternetExplorer);
    web.StopWebServer();
```

But not sure where my Test.html should be and how I can run my [TestMethod] in the Test.html context. How I can dinamicaly create elements in Test.html?

Answer (score 0):

Test.html should be a simple HTML file in your solution. Your test method is simply running IE and going to this page to run all the tests. You dynamically create new elements depending on how you layout the HTML.

Comment: I have added test.html to my Unit test project, added reference to Qunit.js, but when i debug 
web.RunTest(testUri, WebBrowser.InternetExplorer);

My page just is not found and 404 is returned.

Should this work ?

Uri testUri = web.GetTestUri("/Test.html");
    WebTestResult ieResult = web.RunTest(testUri, WebBrowser.InternetExplorer);
Document.CreateElement("div");

Comment: It all depends on where is the root folder. Sounds like test.html is not in the root.

Comment: Test.html is in the root, JS files are in Scripts folder where they were put by Nuget, but I could not load JS files from the browser also.

Answer (score 0):

See this sample (amongst others) at https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/cc/samples/Photos/PhotoListTests

See the sample for how it sets up the root path for the server.

One thing to check for is that you've marked the build action for Test.html as Content so it gets copied over as part of building the test project.

Hope that helps.